# Google Chrome Extension. Get json data locally

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My structure is shown below:
[image]

My manifest.json is shown below:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Doktor-MD",
"description": "Tarayıcı üzerinden Doktor-MD'de link paylaşımı yapabilirsiniz.",
"version": "1.0",

"permissions": [
"http://www.google.com/"
],

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "index.html"
}
}
```

My index.html is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=utf8>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>  
<script src="doktormdcore.js"></script>
<title>Doktor TV Md</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDataFunction()
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; //  Implemented elsewhere.
        xmlHttpRequest.open("GET",  chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json'), true);
        xmlHttpRequest.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>GetData</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="GetData" value="Getir"     onclick="GetDataFunction"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My config.json data(example data) is shown below:

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup   Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages  such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to get json data from my config.json. But how can i test this code to ensure that they are working. And do you think am i correct? Is this right way to get json value from locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Chrome 29, the only way to retrieve the content of a file inside the extension package is XHR and this is the correct way.

As of Chrome 29, the new [chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) enables you to access files inside the package with HTML5 FileSystem API (See also http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/, http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DirectoryEntry).

However, the reason why your code doesn't work is pointed out by Rob W in the comment.